# Vibrations and Torque Converter Failure

Tags: automatic-transmission, torque-converter, failure-modes

I've read in various places that one cause of vibrations when shifting from Park to Drive in an ATX is impending torque converter failure.  Another person [asked about the different ways in which a torque converter may fail](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/19050/7132), and I was wondering which particular failure mode this symptom would correlate to.