# How does a lock-up torque converter work, exactly?

Tags: automatic-transmission, torque-converter

I am familiar with the general workings of a torque converter. The engine-side blade pushes the fluid, the fluid spins the transmission-side blade. What I am all fuzzy about is, for lock-up torque converters, the tranny-side blade gets physically bonded to the engine-side blade above certain RPMs.

**HOW** does this happen? Is it a clutch-like friction thing? I've read different things in different places, so are there different implementations from different manufacturers?

Comment: In case anyone is wondering what's what inside the TC, [here is an answer I gave about TC function](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/19038/4152). It also describes the parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an internal clutch that locks the converter when engaged by the torque converter clutch solenoid. Fluid pressure it routed through the input shaft into the converter clutch, which engages the clutch.

If it is non electronic transmission it uses a pressure switch inside the transmission to engage the solenoid (gm calls it a tcc solenoid) at a given speed and current gear (gear is usually 3rd and overdrive, if electronic, the trans computer controls lockup using the solenoid. When it engages it depends on make/model of transmission and software programming.

[image]

Comment: How is the solenoid engaged to cause the clutch to work? What is the chain of the mechanism? The solenoid *acts on the clutch how* to cause it to lock up?